# MediaDevices.getUserMedia() permission denied in webview while camera is allowed

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I’m trying to use MediaDevices.getUserMedia() api in my webview app, but after a lot of effort I keep getting “permission denied” error even though camera access is allowed, here is what i added

app.module.ts

```
import { AndroidPermissions } from '@ionic-native/android-permissions/ngx';

...

providers: [    
AndroidPermissions,
]
```

app.component.ts

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA).then(
    result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
    err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA)
  );
  
  this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.CAMERA]);
```

config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-android-permissions" spec="1.1.2" />
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/webrtc-adapter/out/adapter.js"
            ]
```

build.gradle

```
implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
```

In my web use api

```
function startVideo() {
 const constraints = { audio: false, video: { facingMode: "user" } }
 navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
 .then(function(mediaStream) {
 video.srcObject = mediaStream;
 video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
  };
 })
 .catch(function(err) { showAlert(err.name + ": " + err.message); });
```

}

It working on browser but not in my ionic app on both cordova and capacitor.
Can anyone point out where I am missing?

Comment: Does this help? https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/does-getusermedia-works-in-ionic-webview-in-ios-app/204744

Comment: I'm trying it on android